# Weird process CPU time output on Ubuntu under Amazon EC2

Tags: linux, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, ps

I have just started a large instance using ami-fa01f193 AMI. When I use ps aux, a bunch of random processes will show HUGE numbers for the CPU time used. Looks like some sort of overflow. Did someone see this before and how do I fix this?

Here is a sample output:

```
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
    1 ?        Ss     0:00 /sbin/init
    2 ?        S      0:00 [kthreadd]
    3 ?        S      0:00 [migration/0]
    4 ?        S    17179869:11 [ksoftirqd/0]
    5 ?        S      0:00 [watchdog/0]
    6 ?        S    17179869:11 [events/0]
    7 ?        S      0:00 [cpuset]
    8 ?        S      0:00 [khelper]
    9 ?        S      0:00 [netns]
   10 ?        S      0:00 [async/mgr]
   11 ?        S      0:00 [xenwatch]
   12 ?        S      0:00 [xenbus]
   14 ?        S      0:00 [migration/1]
   15 ?        S    17179869:11 [ksoftirqd/1]
   16 ?        S      0:00 [watchdog/1]
   17 ?        S    17179869:11 [events/1]
   18 ?        S      0:00 [sync_supers]
   19 ?        S      0:00 [bdi-default]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL/DR:  Known Issue with Ubuntu 10.04 LTS on Amazon EC2 Nehalem instances

---

According to [Mike Heffner](https://silverline.librato.com/blog/main/EC2_Users_Should_be_Cautious_When_Booting_Ubuntu_10_04_AMIs) (of Librato's Silverline):

> During conversations with other tech
>   companies we learned of an issue when
>   running the Ubuntu 10.04 LTS release
>   on certain Amazon EC2 servers -- the
>   same environment as our backend
>   servers. The issue appeared to be
>   triggered when launching the Ubuntu
>   10.04 LTS release on hypervisors running on Intel Xeon Series 55xx
>   (Nehalem) CPUs. For example, some
>   Cassandra users were reporting that
>   nodes would completely freeze up for
>   extended periods of time. We
>   identified that we only saw the large
>   CPU spikes in our backend system CPU
>   graphs when we had launched an E5507
>   backed instance.

Mike recommends the following workarounds while a kernel patch for Ubuntu 10.01:
There are a number of approaches users can take to avoid being impacted by this:

1. Update to a newer Ubuntu release,
   for example, Ubuntu 10.10. Since
   Ubuntu 10.04, the Xen patches are
   better integrated into the kernel
   avoiding the requirement to backport
   them to 2.6.32. Users have reported
   that the original process lockups
   don’t occur with the Ubuntu 10.10
   images.
2. For users with environments
   currently dependent on the Ubuntu
   10.04 environment (we still have some ourselves) we have modified our
   OPS scripts to throw out instances
   that boot with the Nehalem CPUs and
   reprovision until we get an E5430
   machine. We have noticed that in
   some AZs we see more Nehalem’s than
   in others which likely points to AZs
   with more recent hardware
   deployments. Obviously this approach
   is not sustainable on a whole as
   more users seek out the older E5430
   CPUs and Amazon further invests in
   the Nehalem architecture, so we are
   actively working to migrate our
   10.04 systems to 10.10.
3. For advanced users, building a custom 2.6.32
   kernel that contains the patchset
   from the [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/727459) is an option.
   There are also some custom kernels
   and AMIs in this bug report that
   users have reported success with.

Answer (score 0):

A similar thing happened to me on a Centos server.  A full, cold reboot fixed the problem.  Of course, I don't know how you would go about a cold reboot on a virtual machine though...

[On a freshly-rebooted server why would the CPU running time of processes be huge?](https://serverfault.com/questions/614862/on-a-freshly-rebooted-server-why-would-the-cpu-running-time-of-processes-be-huge/615073#615073)